# How to put a int value in a ToolStripMenuItem name?

Tags: c#

I have an x number of ToolStripMenuItems which i want to add in a menuStrip the problem is these menuItems have different actions and the actions are given by the user in a document.I want to put int variables in the ToolStripMenuItem name because i need to attach a different event to them(the event are given by the user).
I also tried:

```
ToolStripMenuItem item + a = new ToolStripMenuItem();
```

But dosen't work.

Comment: Use an array or list of `ToolStripMenuItem`s

Comment: You're looking for the wonders of arrays.

Comment: O yea i forget about array let me try if it works.